# Draw a vertical line representing the current date in amcharts gantt chart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

*Draw a vertical line in Current month. here the sample code
 * https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PgELdM
* and this is what I want to achieve
 * https://ibb.co/XjVn4WC

```
console.log("thank you");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [axis guides to draw single lines beneath the chart](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/axis-ranges/#Single_lines). E.g.

```js
var range = dateAxis.axisRanges.create();
range.date = new Date("2016-03-14");
range.grid.stroke = am4core.color("red");
range.grid.strokeWidth = 2;
range.grid.strokeOpacity = 1;
```

Demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/bb11ebefe894ad526d4bd959fccccf08

If you need a line on top of the various series, what you can do is make a full height [line](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/line/) (`y1`, `y2` at `0`, not sure how to get the top of the chart value... says it only takes `number`s meaning pixels, but maybe it can work with `am4core.percent(100)`?), for its `x` you'll have to convert date to a coordinate on the chart (the [`dateAxis` will probably have methods](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateaxis/#Methods) for that), and place it in the `chart.plotContainer`.