# Draw a moving vertical line representing the current date in amcharts gantt chart?

Tags: amcharts4

I am using amCharts4 and is able to plot a vertical line on my Gantt chart representing the current date time as described in the following : [Draw a vertical line representing the current date in amcharts gantt chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55719235/draw-a-vertical-line-representing-the-current-date-in-amcharts-gantt-chart). However, how do I make the vertical line move every sec on the chart based on the current time? Here is the code :

```
var range = dateAxis.axisRanges.create();
range.date = new Date("2020-10-29 07:04:56");
range.grid.stroke = am4core.color("red");
range.grid.strokeWidth = 2;
range.grid.strokeOpacity = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `setInterval` that runs every second to update the date on your range, like this:

```
// First, create your range marker
var range = dateAxis.axisRanges.create();
range.grid.stroke = am4core.color("red");
range.grid.strokeWidth = 2;
range.grid.strokeOpacity = 1;
range.date = new Date();

// Then, update the position of your range marker every second
range.date = new Date(2018, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0);
var timeout = window.setInterval(() => {
  range.date = new Date(range.date.getTime() + 1000);
}, 1000);

chart.events.on('beforedisposed', () => {
   clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

[Here is an example](https://codepen.io/frankfajardo/pen/yLJKONq?editors=0010)

**UPDATE**

One thing you want to do with the timeout is to also clear it when you no longer need it--- for example,  when you dispose the chart or the marker.

I have updated the code above to clear it before the chart is disposed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and a great example! I can now make the marker move but it seem to move too fast. In your example, the marker took about 20 sec to move from 8:30 - 9:00. I changed the range.date.getTime() + (seconds * 1000) to just range.date.getTime() + seconds. Initially the marker seemed to move correctly but after that it started to move too fast as compared to the x axis time value again. Here is my test code : https://codepen.io/albert-ang/pen/VwjXKdo.

Comment: @AlbertAng, oops, my code was wrong. I was adding more than 1 second to the time on subsequent loops.Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated it.

Comment: thank you for the update! I changed your range.date.setTime(range.date.getTime() + 1000); to range.date = new Date(range.date.setTime(range.date.getTime() + 1000)); and it works perfectly. Otherwise the range marker would not move. Here is my updated test code : codepen.io/albert-ang/pen/VwjXKdo . Thank you very much for your kind assistance.

Comment: @AlbertAng, actually, the more concise statement should be `range.date = new Date(range.date.getTime() + 1000)`, dropping the `setTime()`.

Comment: @AlbertAng, you could [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you believe I answered your question.